# Authorization_RequestDenied when i have access token code

Tags: c#, webforms, azure-active-directory

Blockquoteafter access token when I called graph API that returns Authorization_RequestDenied request for the access token

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient()) 
{
   var requestParameters = new NameValueCollection();
   requestParameters.Add("resource", resource);
   requestParameters.Add("client_id", clientID); 
   requestParameters.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
   requestParameters.Add("client_secret", secret);
   var url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token";
   var  responsebytes = await webClient.UploadValuesTaskAsync(url,"POST",requestParameters);
   var responsebody =Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
   var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responsebody);
   var token = obj["access_token"].Value<string>();
   access_token = token;  
}
```

after when i request form get the user list from Azure AD by this way

```
 public async Task<List<listItems>> GetData1( string token)
 {
     HttpClient http = new HttpClient(); 
     string query = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users";
     HttpRequestMessage httpClient = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, query);
     httpClient.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
     var res = await http.SendAsync(httpClient);
     var res1= await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     List<listItems> lstUsers = new List<listItems>();
     JObject results = JObject.Parse(res1); listItems itm;
      foreach (var Jelem in results["value"])
      { 
          string id = (string)Jelem["id"];
          string displayName = (string)Jelem["displayName"];
          itm = new listItems(); itm.id = id;
          itm.displayname = displayName; lstUsers.Add(itm);
      }
      return lstUsers;
 }
```

than i got "error": `{ "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied", "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.", "innerError": { "request-id": "1ba8a3e3-7e27-4bad-affd-6929b9af3a9f", "date": "2019-03-26T10:56:26" }` the above error

please help me to solve this error

Comment: holy unreadablenes..  I cant even make out whats going on

Comment: now you can read dear @BugFinder

Comment: Ok, so debug time.  Are you sure you're getting the correct response in the first chunk of code? is responsebody a token?  there are a lot of variables not defined here.  see [mcve], are you sure the user you are logging in with has sufficient rights in the graph website

Comment: Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET web form how I will work on @BugFinder

Comment: dear @BugFinder, do you have a sample of how to Get access tokens to call Microsoft Graph from asp.net web form, not in asp.net MVC.

Comment: It's a shame that LMGTFY links aren't allowed, have you tried Googling for how to retrieve Microsoft Graph tokens? It's the first result - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview

Comment: @CharitPandey If my answer helpful You can mark it by clicking on checkbox beside your question. So it would be easier for other as the web form example is rare due to MVC development. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUSE**

This problem occurs because the application does not have the required permission to access the user information. So you need to assign necessary privileged for this request.

**SOLUTION**

To access [*https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) API One of the following permissions is required.

**[Permission type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) (from least to most privileged)**

> Delegated (work or school account)    User.Read, User.ReadWrite,
>   User.ReadBasic.All,
>
> User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All,
>   Directory.ReadWrite.All,
>
> Directory.AccessAsUser.All
>
> Delegated (personal Microsoft account)    User.Read, User.ReadWrite
>
> Application   User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All,
>
> Directory.ReadWrite.All

See the screen shot below:

[image]

**AZURE PORTAL WAY OUT**

To assign permission on azure portal see the screen shot below:

[image]

**ASP.NET WEB FORM EXAMPLE:**

**1. Add New Aspx page To project**

Take a new web form,  here I have taken as Token.aspx and set its property like below

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Async="true"
 CodeBehind="Token.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormTest.Token" %>
```

**2. Add New Reference from Nuget**

In your project reference add a new service reference from nuget package manager console Like below:

[image]

**3. Token.aspx.cs**

Paste following code outside the scope of **Page_Load** method You might need to add following reference on your namespace once you encounter missing reference error.

> using System.Net.Http;
>
> using System.Net.Http.Headers;

```
class AccessToken
        {
            public string access_token { get; set; }
        }
        // Resource Owner Password Credentials Format
        private async Task<string> GetTokenByROPCFormat()
        {

            string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantId/oauth2/token";
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

            req.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["grant_type"] = "password",
                ["client_id"] = "ApplicationID",
                ["client_secret"] = "ApplicationSecret",
                ["resource"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com",
                ["username"] = "userEmailwithAccessPrivilege",
                ["password"] = "YourPassword"
            });

            dynamic json;
            dynamic results;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var res = await client.SendAsync(req);

            json = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //Token Output
            results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessToken>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(results.access_token);


            //New Block For Accessing Data from Microsoft Graph API
            HttpClient newClient = new HttpClient();

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", results.access_token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await newClient.SendAsync(request);

            string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Responsed data Is-\n\n" + output + "");
            return output;
        }
```

**4. Call GetTokenByROPCFormat() Method inside Page_Load**

Now call **GetTokenByROPCFormat** inside the **Page_Load** like below

```
RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetTokenByROPCFormat));
```

**5. Token Output**

If you set debugger on **results variable** you would get your token like below

[image]

**6. Access Microsoft Graph API**

Now move to following line and set your debugger like below

> string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

You would see following output

[image]

Hope it would solve your problem. Thank you.

Comment: @CharitPandey I have Updated my answer with aspx web form example try it out. thank you.

Comment: thanks,@Md Farid Uddin Kiron, it was helpful for me.

Comment: @CharitPandey Glad to know, happy coding!

Comment: I m also happy to know you.